# save element as local variable in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a file where I define a directive in the following structure:

```
(function (angular) {

    angular.module('moduleName').directive('directiveName', function () {
           function Controller($scope){
                ...
           }

           function Link(scope, element, attrs){
                ...
           }

           function someHelperFucntion(){
                ...
           }

           return {
               scope: {
                   someData: "="            
               },
               controller: Controller,
               restrict: 'E',
               templateUrl: "templateUrl",
               link: Link
          }

    }

}
```

I want to access element and scope in *someHelperFucntion*. *someHelperFucntion* can be either called directly from the *Link* function or can be a callback of some jquery/jquery plugin event.
So passing element and scope as variables to *someHelperFucntion* is not possible (if it's a callback function).

So how can I access element and scope in *someHelperFucntion*?

Comment: can you show how you're calling this? Why can't you define `someHelperFunction` within the link function where the scope would be available?

Comment: Two reasons: 1. What if I want to use same function in the controller as well? 2. It looks clearer to me when all helper function are defined separately and not inside the link function.

Comment: If you want to use the function in the controller then it's much better to define it on the scope. In the link function, you can set `scope.someHelperFunction` and in the controller you can access it via `$scope.someHelpferFunction`. Since the function requires the scope and element, it looks cleaner to me to have this function on the scope rather than floating in nothingness.